# SQL: Using values from case expression for next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to think of a more efficient way to write my query. I have a long case statement that aggregates accounting GLs, my goal being aggregation in three columns.

```
Select 
    Month, Sum(Value1), Sum (Budget),
    Case 
       When Field1 In (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004) Then 'Hardware Expense'
       When Field1 In (2001, 2002, 2003, 2004) Then 'Software Expense'
       When Field1 In (3001, 3002, 3003, 3004) Then 'Product Sales' 
    End As "Aggregation1",
    Case 
       When Field1 In (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 2001, 2002, 2003) Then 'Expenses'
       When Field1 In (3001, 3002, 3003, 3004) Then 'Sales' End As "Aggregation2"
```

While this works, my actual statement is much longer. Ideally, I'd call 'Hardware Expense' and 'Software Expense' as variables.

```
When Aggregation1 In ('Hardware Expense', 'Software Expense') then 'Expenses'
```

With the final output being

```
Month, Sum(Value1), Sum (Budget), Aggregation1, Aggregation2, Aggregation3
```

Thanks for taking a look!
-Mark

Comment: The sample data suggests that the codes' first digit is common for a group. So something like `CASE field1 / 1000 WHEN 1 THEN 'Hardware Expense' WHEN 2 THEN 'Software Expense'...` could shorten things a little. Another option would be another table (or two) that holds the strings you want for each code. You could then simply join it on `field1`.

Comment: With the lookup table, you could have ranges that define the names, e.g. `Software Expense  2000  2999` and `Expense  1000  2999`

Comment: Agreed with @LaughingVergil that a look-up table might be a more elegant solution. The look-up table could also look like (Field1, AggregatedInType1, AggregatedInType2, AggregatedInType3..... 1001, 1, 0, 1) or something like that to give you even greater flexibility. Then, you can join your main table with the look-up table and have a more elegant aggregation code.

Comment: Instead of a hard-coded lookup table, the aggregation types could also be fields in the table where all these numbers are the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup table(s) can help here, but as-is you can use the `CROSS APPLY` operator to create named columns on the fly, which you can reference in the same query.

Note, how freshly defined `Aggregation1` column is used later in the query.

```
SELECT
    Month, Sum(Value1), Sum (Budget),
    A1.Aggregation1,
    A2.Aggregation2
FROM
    SomeTable
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN Field1 In (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004) Then 'Hardware Expense'
                WHEN Field1 In (2001, 2002, 2003, 2004) Then 'Software Expense'
                WHEN Field1 In (3001, 3002, 3003, 3004) Then 'Product Sales' 
            END AS Aggregation1
    ) AS A1
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN Aggregation1 In ('Hardware Expense', 'Software Expense') then 'Expenses'
                WHEN Aggregation1 In ('Product Sales') then 'Sales'
            END AS Aggregation2
    ) AS A2
;
```